What mathematical representation/technique can I use to verify the relationship between a convex polyhedron and its dual
From [1]

It is easily seen that the convex hull of the union of $A^D$ and $B^D$ is the dual of the intersection of $A$ and $B$.

where the definition of dual in [1] is:

The dual $A^D$ of $A$ is obtained by reinterpreting the coefficients
$n_1(f)$, $n_2(f)$, $n_3(f)$ of each face $f\in F_A$ as the coordinates
of a corresponding vertex $v_f$ of $A^D$. Conversely, the coordinates
$x_1(v)$, $x_2(v)$, $x_3(v)$ of each vertex of $V_A$ are reinterpreted
as the coefficients of a corresponding face $f_v$ of $A^D$. This
transformation may be regarded as a conventional dualization about the
unit sphere with center at the origin where points at distance $l$
from the origin are transformed into planes at distance $\frac{1}{l}$
from the origin and vice versa ([7, p. 233]). A similar procedure
allow us to form the dual of $B$.

[7] Ewald, Günter. "Geometry: an introduction" (1971).

What steps would verify that the convex hull of the union of the dual of $A$ ($A^D$) and the dual of $B$ ($B^D$), where $A$ and $B$ are 2 convex polyhedron at the origin, is the intersection of $A$ and $B$.
[1] Muller, D.E. and Preparata, F.P., 1978. Finding the intersection of two convex polyhedra, Theoretical Computer Science, 7(2), pp.217-236. https://doi.org/10.1016/0304-3975(78)90051-8

What happens when you apply the definition of "dual"?

Your title isn't adapted to your question which deals with the dualization of operations : intersection $\leftrightarrow$ Convex hull of union.

I found the light at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(mathematics)#Duality_in_logic_and_set_theory by replacing the convex polyhedron with the boundaries between a set and its complement.
